# The Decorator Design Pattern: What is meant by adding functionality?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, decorator

I have just gone into studying the Decorator Design Pattern using C#.

I have made an example which kinda functions as I think it is intended except for one thing.

I kinda understood that the whole point of the pattern is to add functionality to an object dynamically.

So when I create an object like this:

```
Inventory a = new Ashbringer(new TravelersBagpack());
a.Execute();
```

Then I kinda expected that the point was that the `a` object would now be able to call the `Execute()` method which only exists in the `Ashbringer` class. Thus adding functionality to the `a` object.

Though this I can't do without adding the `Execute()` method to the `Inventory` interface which would ultimately mean I would have to implement the `Execute()` method to all the classes implementing `Inventory` Interface or the abstract Decorator.

Perhaps there is a thing or two I don't know about interfaces or perhaps I misunderstand the point of the Decorator Design Pattern?

Comment: My Decorator Design Pattern was highly inspired by this guys solution.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NtXGDTgrTMI

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Decorator pattern is more about changing the behavior of existing methods of an object that you're decorating (wrapping) rather than adding new methods. While the decorator can certainly have its own methods, the intent is that the decorator can be treated as if it were the object it is wrapping.

Consider the `Stream` classes in .NET. `Stream` is a common abstract class that simply defines a basic interface for reading and writing to streams, but a concrete subclass like `FileStream` provides the implementation to read/write files. But if you want to add buffering or compression behavior to a `FileStream` class, you wouldn't want to subclass `FileStream`, because then your subclass wouldn't work with `NetworkStream` or `MemoryStream` unless you also made subclasses for them.

That's where the Decorator pattern comes in. A `BufferedStream` or `CompressedStream` class can "decorate" another instance of a `Stream`. You can read/write from `BufferedStream` or `CompressedStream` the same as you would read/write against any undecorated stream. It does this by overriding the methods of the `Stream` class, adding its functionality by doing whatever to the bytes coming into or out of the stream, then passing them onto the wrapped object, whether it's a `FileStream`, `NetworkStream`, or even another decorator.

But going back to your WoW example, maybe a better example would be an `EnchantedWeapon` class or a `TransmogrifiedWeapon` class that would act as decorators of a Weapon class. Then you could do something like:

```
Weapon w = new Ashbringer();
w = new TransmogrifiedWeapon(w, "Exodar Bastard Sword");
w = new EnchantedWeapon(w, "Scourgebane");
w.Render();
```

Of course, that would obviously throw an exception, because everybody knows that Ashbringer can't be transmogged. :)

Comment: Haha! I get it way better now! Everything is just way simpler when you try to explain it in WoW terms xD 

So Weapon has method called Hit() for an example and Ashbringer Implements this to do 10 dmg for an example and then we decorate Ashbringer with EnchantedWeapon which would add 5 dmg to the hit() method. So the point is to add functionality to the methods of an object and not add more methods to an object.

Comment: Right. A good indicator that you're looking at a job for decorators is where the problem *could* be solved by subclassing, but when doing so would limit its usefulness or require many subclasses. (i.e. you *could* make an EnchantedAshbringer, but then you'd need one for every enchantable weapon.)

Comment: Decorators are easy when you put your faith in the light :)

Answer (score 2):

The idea in the decorator pattern is that you extend the functionality of a method. It is for cases when inheritance becomes to complex and the functionality needs to be in seperated classes.

A good example is calculating prices. Imagine you want to add fees for special services like a nicer package, faster shipping, insurance.

Now you have your `Product` class with a `CalculatePrice` method.

```
public class Product
{
    public double CalculatePrice()
    {
        // 10 is the products price
        return 10.0D;
    }
}
```

As next you can create a `ProductDecorator` which doesn't call his base classes method but the one of the product it was given.

```
public abstract class ProductDecorator : Product
{
    private readonly Product _product;

    public ProductDecorator(Product product)
    {
        _product = product;
    }

    public override double CalculatePrice()
    {
        return _product.CalculatePrice();
    }
}
```

Now this price has to change when you want extra services like the metioned above. So you can create decorator classes for them.

```
public class ShippingDecorator : ProductDecorator
{
    public ShippingDecorator(Product product)
        : base(product)
    { }

    public override double CalculatePrice()
    {
        // shipping coasts 5
        return base.CalculatePrice() + 5;
    }
}

public class InsuranceDecorator : ProductDecorator
{
...
```

If you wanted to use inheritance for this it would not be usefull as it would be to complex. (To many classes)

Now you can use it like this.

```
var product = new Product();
product = new ShippingDecorator(product);
product = new InsuranceDecorator(product);
...
```

Typicly you also have a factory which creates your object or you can use the builder patten.

Answer (score 1):

It's not supposed to add anything new to the interface,  it's trying to decorate existing functionality.

So you'd extend what the Execute of TravelersBagpack does in someway.

Answer (score 1):

In the context of streams, let's say you wanted to write to a file. It would look like this:

```
using(var fileStream = new FileStream(...))
{ ... }
```

Now let's say you wanted that file to be encrypted. You can do this with a second stream using the decorator pattern:

```
using(var fileStream = new FileStream(...))
using(var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(fileStream))
{ ... }
```

Now let's say you wanted that encrypted file to be compressed. Decorator to the rescue again!

```
using(var fileStream = new FileStream(...))
using(var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(fileStream))
using(var zipStream = new ZipArchive(cryptoStream))
{ ... }
```

...you get the picture.

Each stream adds functionality on the process of "writing" a stream.